# Angular Typescript: Add Dynamic CSS reading from Array

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, angular8

How do I dynamically add SCSS styles reading from an Angular array?
We have an angular array with following members.

```
class ItemList{
    productName: string;
    highlight: boolean;
}
```

It contains members `{food, true},  {car, true}, {book, false}, {desk, true}, etc`
Following members with true, need certain styling.
All members in array, with true should create the following.

**SCSS:**

```
.food{
background-color:blue
}

.car{
background-color:blue
}

.desk{
background-color:blue
}
```

Comment: You can not "add" SCSS rules at runtime, because SCCS compiles to CSS on build time. Can you please explain use-case of your approach in more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this is your Component TS:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.full;
  items: Array<Item> = [
    { productName: 'food', highlight: true},
    { productName: 'car', highlight: true},
    { productName: 'book', highlight: false},
    { productName: 'desk', highlight: true}
  ];
}
```

This is your CSS File:

```
.title {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.food {
  background-color:blue
}

.car {
  background-color:blue
}

.desk {
  background-color:blue
}
```

You can use `ngClass` to make this work:

```
<ul>
  <li 
    *ngFor="let item of items"
    [ngClass]="item.highlight ? item.productName : ''">
    {{ item.productName }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgqwsy?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: how do I pass as blob to a child components, i know ngfor, just don't want it only tie to the li line element,  see I have elements below in child components, will use :host later to apply the stylings generated